IIS - Tomcat (MicroStrategy Library) - 404 error
After upgrading from MicroStrategy Library version 2021 to MicroStrategy One, I encountered an issue accessing the Library page on the server side (IIS). Despite functioning correctly on localhost, the server returned a 404 error:

I followed the setup steps outlined in the link below to configure the Library on both the previous and current versions:
https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html.
I have checked steps and paths multiple time but nothing changed.
I have noticed that isapi_redirect.log file was not generated in the expected folder, as it was in the previous version:

Since log file is not created my assumption is that something went wrong with isapi_redirect.dll file.
Does anyone has an idea why this happening?
Kind regards,
Marijana Kalanj
I have tried setup Library on IIS.
I expected successful configuration following steps from the link: https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html .
Server returned 404 error, isapi_redirect.log file was not created.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Hi @samwu, do you have any recommendations on how to track logs on Windows? The logs in the inetpub directory aren't providing much useful information. Thanks in advance for any advice.

You can refer to this link: Troubleshoot failed requests using tracing in IIS.

MicroStrategy Library doesn't support IIS. You need tomcat 10 to run new releases. And I do not recommend use IIS even for MicroStrategy Web.
